# Django 1.8.4 app fails while serving GET request on CentOS - Same app works on Ubuntu with same packages installed

Tags: django, python-2.7, pip

On CentOS, the application starts, but when I navigate my browser to the server's port 8000, I get this error:

```
June 12, 2016 - 20:03:23
Django version 1.8.4, using settings 'mobilify.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 218, in get_response
    response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 264, in handle_uncaught_exception
    if resolver.urlconf_module is None:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in urlconf_module
    self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/nginxsite/mobilify/mobilify/mobilify/urls.py", line 8, in <module>
    admin.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/nginxsite/mobilify/mobilify/app/client/admin.py", line 51, in <module>
    class ClientAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/home/nginxsite/mobilify/mobilify/app/client/admin.py", line 65, in ClientAdminForm
    class Meta:
  File "/home/nginxsite/mobilify/mobilify/app/client/admin.py", line 98, in Meta
    select2_options={"width": "220px"}
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django_select2/widgets.py", line 112, in __init__
    super(Select2Mixin, self).__init__(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 10 arguments (3 given)
[12/Jun/2016 20:03:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

The very same app runs smoothly on Ubuntu 14.04 with the same Django version installed. I'm out of ideas here, please help me.

The CentOS machine has the following packages installed:

```
amqp (1.4.9)
anyjson (0.3.3)
BeautifulSoup (3.2.1)
beautifulsoup4 (4.4.1)
billiard (3.3.0.23)
bs4 (0.0.1)
celery (3.1.18)
certifi (2015.4.28)
cffi (1.6.0)
chardet (2.1.1)
Cheetah (2.4.4)
cryptography (1.4)
Django (1.8.4)
django-appconf (1.0.2)
django-braces (1.8.0)
django-countries (3.4.1)
django-debug-toolbar (1.3.0)
django-extensions (1.5.5)
django-floppyforms (1.6.2)
django-haystack (2.3.1)
django-location-field (1.6.1)
django-mptt (0.7.4)
django-pam (1.1.2)
django-paypal (0.3.2)
django-phonenumber-field (0.7.2)
Django-Select2 (4.3.1)
django-smart-selects (1.2.2)
django-suit (0.2.14)
django-uuidfield (0.5.0)
easy-thumbnails (2.2)
enum34 (1.0.4)
html5lib (0.999)
idna (2.0)
ipaddress (1.0.14)
ipython (3.2.1)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
jsonfield (1.0.3)
jsonpatch (1.3)
jsonpointer (1.10)
kombu (3.0.35)
Markdown (2.6.6)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
ndg-httpsclient (0.4.1)
pbr (1.10.0)
phonenumbers (7.4.2)
phonenumberslite (7.4.2)
Pillow (2.9.0)
pip (8.1.2)
prettytable (0.7.2)
psycopg2 (2.6)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycparser (2.14)
pyOpenSSL (16.0.0)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
python-mimeparse (1.5.2)
python-pam (1.8.2)
pytz (2016.4)
redis (2.10.3)
requests (2.7.0)
setuptools (3.3)
six (1.10.0)
sqlparse (0.1.19)
stevedore (1.15.0)
Twisted (16.2.0)
unicode-slugify (0.1.3)
Unidecode (0.4.19)
urllib3 (1.16)
uWSGI (2.0.11.1)
virtualenv (15.0.2)
virtualenv-clone (0.2.6)
virtualenvwrapper (4.7.1)
wheel (0.24.0)
zope.interface (4.2.0)
```

On Ubuntu, these are installed:

```
amqp (1.4.6)
anyjson (0.3.3)
apt-xapian-index (0.45)
argparse (1.2.1)
arrow (0.6.0)
BeautifulSoup (3.2.1)
beautifulsoup4 (4.4.1)
billiard (3.3.0.20)
bs4 (0.0.1)
celery (3.1.18)
certifi (2015.04.28)
cffi (1.1.2)
chardet (2.0.1)
Cheetah (2.4.4)
cloud-init (0.7.5)
colorama (0.2.5)
configobj (4.7.2)
cryptography (0.9.3)
Django (1.8.4)
django-braces (1.8.0)
django-countries (3.3)
django-debug-toolbar (1.3.0)
django-extensions (1.5.5)
django-haystack (2.3.1)
django-location-field (1.6)
django-mptt (0.7.4)
django-paypal (0.2.5)
django-phonenumber-field (0.7.2)
Django-Select2 (4.3.1)
django-smart-selects (1.1.1)
django-suit (0.2.14)
django-suit-redactor (0.0.2)
django-uuidfield (0.5.0)
easy-thumbnails (2.2)
enum34 (1.0.4)
html5lib (0.999)
idna (2.0)
ipaddress (1.0.14)
ipython (3.2.1)
Jinja2 (2.7.3)
jsonfield (1.0.3)
jsonpatch (1.3)
jsonpointer (1.0)
kombu (3.0.26)
Landscape-Client (14.12)
lxml (3.6.0)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
ndg-httpsclient (0.4.0)
oauth (1.0.1)
PAM (0.4.2)
pdb (0.1)
phonenumbers (7.0.8)
Pillow (2.9.0)
pip (1.5.4)
prettytable (0.7.2)
psycopg2 (2.6)
pyasn1 (0.1.8)
pycparser (2.14)
pycurl (7.19.3)
pyOpenSSL (0.15.1)
pyserial (2.6)
python-apt (0.9.3.5ubuntu2)
python-dateutil (2.4.2)
python-debian (0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2)
python-gnupg (0.3.7)
python-magic (0.4.6)
pytz (2015.4)
PyYAML (3.11)
redis (2.10.3)
requests (2.7.0)
setuptools (3.3)
six (1.9.0)
sqlparse (0.1.16)
ssh-import-id (3.21)
Twisted-Core (13.2.0)
Twisted-Names (13.2.0)
Twisted-Web (13.2.0)
unicode-slugify (0.1.3)
Unidecode (0.04.18)
urllib3 (1.7.1)
uWSGI (2.0.11.1)
wheel (0.24.0)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
zope.interface (4.0.5)
```

Contents of the requirements.txt (all have been installed):

```
Django==1.8.2
Pillow==2.8.2
celery==3.1.18
django-braces==1.8.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.3.0
django-extensions==1.5.5
django-haystack==2.3.1
django-mptt==0.7.4
redis==2.10.3
requests==2.7.0
unicode-slugify==0.1.3
psycopg2==2.6
django-uuidfield==0.5.0
Jinja2==2.7.3
BeautifulSoup==3.2.1
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
jsonfield==1.0.3
django-suit==0.2.7
```

Comment: The "crash log" seems to incriminate something with Django-Select2, which doesn't seem to be in your requirements. Also, are you comparing the same things (django dev server on Ubuntu vs. django dev server on CentOS, python 2.7 on each side). Also, this kind of dependency issues would be easier to isolate with a virtualenv.

Comment: Yes, I'm comparing the same things (Python 2.7 etc.). How would one go about isolating the issue using virtualenv?

Comment: I would use it to mirror configurations, starting by a blank virtualenv on the Ubuntu machine, installing libraries from requirements.txt, running django in the env to see if it works, updating requirements if needed, then doing the same on CentOS.